# WSMan Installation on Mac M1-chip

Tags: macos, powershell

When I get to the "Install-WSMan" command in Powershell 7.2.2, I get the following error:

fatal error: /opt/local/bin/lipo: unknown flag: -archs

Any thoughts on resolution?

Comment: I think you can add `-Verbose` to see more output and get a better idea of what the issue may be. There are some closed issues related to installing on Mac's with M1 processors [here](https://github.com/jborean93/omi/issues?q=is%3Aissue+M1+is%3Aclosed+). I'd consider logging an issue there if those solutions do not work.

Comment: Not having `-archs` implies that your copy of lipo is from an older version of XCode. (It shouldn't be in `/usr/local/bin` in the first place if you installed it the right way; is this maybe something in your system on account of Homebrew? Apple's copy will be in `/usr/bin`, not `/usr/local/bin`)